# curl vs normal file download

Tags: php, performance, curl, download

I want to know which one is better for trans-loading large files on my server. I have 2 options using curl or normal php fopen or fwrite. Below are both implementations. Could you please suggest which one is better and with reasons if possible.

Curl implementation

```
$fp = fopen (dirname(__FILE__) . '/localfile.tmp', 'w+');//This is the file where we save the    information
$ch = curl_init(str_replace(" ","%20",$url));//Here is the file we are downloading, replace spaces with %20
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); // write curl response to file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch); // get curl response
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Normal php implementation

```
while(!feof($url)) {                    
 fwrite($filename, fread($file, 1024 * 8 ), 1024 * 8 );
}
```

Comment: Better?  What problems are you facing?

Comment: i want to know which one is best in order to save memory resources and also processing

Comment: Given that they're for use in __different circumstances__, the best one to use is the one that fits your circumstances